# Query returns wrong output result in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to compare array of words with a field of database table which contains more than 2000 entries.
For example user input a string 
"this is good"
It will explode the string into array and than match the words with the database table , such as good exists in the table then it will return the good keyword.
here is my code

```
$cmnt = $request['comment'];
$parse = explode(' ',$cmnt);
$length = count($parse);
for($i = 0; $i < $length ; $i++)
{
    $keyword = Rate::where('keyword',$parse[$i]);
}
if ($keyword != null)
{
    dd($keyword);
}
```

Here is my out put 
[image: My output is displaying the keyword like this in the picture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are over writing value of `$keyword`  in each loop iteration do like this

```
$cmnt = $request['comment'];
$parse = explode(' ',$cmnt);
$parse = array_unique($parse);
$keyword = Rate::whereIn('keyword',$parse);
dd($keyword);
```

Comment: But I want to compare all the values of array thats why I am using for loop , how this can work without iterations?

Comment: the above will create a query like select * from rate where keyword in('this','is', 'good').